# Create a hardcoded Promise<T>[] to return component as there is no backend yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which in future will make a backend call to get data. For now I want to return dummy data to component. How can create a hardcoded `Promise<IMySetting>[]`

```
export function getMySettings(id: number): Promise<IMySetting>[] {
    
    const settings = (
    ): IMySettings => {
        return {
            name: 'test'
        };
    };
const myArray = [setting, setting];
  return ... //How to create an array of Promise<IMySetting>
}
```

```
export interface IMySetting {
    name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your function `async`, and then you can `return` whatever you like which will implicitly resolve to a Promise for you.

```
export interface IMySetting {
    name: string;
}

async function getMySettings(id: number): Promise<IMySetting[]> {   
  return [
    { name: 'test1' },
    { name: 'test2' }
  ];
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPAZWBhmQHM4BvAKDmbiUwFtgAuOAZxig0A3AwC+DBpl7Ek2OOgCusqhCRxqFEuUo1eACgQATHkgXsARmgCUPAApQI7BL2AAeImQpUk1ANoBdAD56FiY4KAoFKDVfMOY6Vg5uOAByVH4ARhS4UQAaOJC2Th404H4AJmzxZn8RUSA)

---

And if you really wanted an an array of promises for some reason, instead of a promise that resolves to an array, you can use `Promise.resolve(value)` to create a promise that is already resolved.

```
export interface IMySetting {
    name: string;
}

function getMySettings(id: number): Promise<IMySetting>[] {   
  return [
    Promise.resolve({ name: 'test1' }),
    Promise.resolve({ name: 'test2' })
  ];
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPAZWBhmQHM4BvAKDmbiUwFtgAuOAZxig0A3AwC+DBugCuSbFQhI41CiXKUavABQIAJjyRT2AIzQBKHgAUoEdgl7AAPETIUqSagD4A2gF16LJjgoCikoRS9A5isbO2AAOmDeCAAbADdgTTpWDm44AHJUfgBGPLhRUwAaSLho23sE4CS0jKy2Th4CxpgAJlLywJ8RUSA)